# Coin and Lottery Question

Tags: probability

[image]

**Attempt:**

For the first part I presume I use bayes' theorem? For the second part, I can't count the number of ways of such a sequence. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: 
$$P(\text{Non-decreasing}) = 1 - P(\text{Decreasing})$$

Comment: @jameselmore I was aware of that, I think im having a problem combinatorically

Comment: does a decreasing sequence mean *strictly* decreasing, or are some draws allowed to equal each other and have the sequence still be decreasing?

Comment: @Brent: *Non-decreasing* generally means that $x_j\le x_k$ whenever $j\le k$. Sometimes called *weakly increasing* or *non-strictly increasing*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, use Bayes' Rule.

2) Hint: A sequence will be non-decreasing if (a) there are *any* repeats, or (b) there are no repeats *and* these distinct numbers (whatever they are) are *not drawn* in strictly decreasing order.

There are $n^r$ ways to draw $r$ numbers with replacement from $n$.  There are $\binom{n}{r}$ ways to draw $r$ distinct numbers (ie without replacement) from $n$.

On the condition that no repeats have been drawn the numbers, whatever they may be, will have $r!$ ways to be arranged.  Of these only one will be strictly decreasing.

So the probability that $r$ drawn from $n$ with replacement will be in a non-strictly-decreasing sequence is: $$\left(1-\dfrac{\binom n r}{n^r}\right) + \dfrac {\binom{n}{r} }{n^r}\Big(1-\tfrac 1 {r!}\Big)$$

Simplify.

Comment: I've got the first part, im still having trouble with the second part.